# I expired some trouble with understanding Java polimorphism

Tags: java, polymorphism, static-methods

```
public class XXX {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        B b = new B();
        b.doY();
    }
}



class A {
    public void doY() {
        XProcedure.doX(this);
    }
}


class B extends A {

    public void doY() {
        super.doY();
        XProcedure.doX(this);
    }
}


class XProcedure {

    public static void doX(A a) {
        System.out.println("AAAA!");
    }

    public static void doX(B b) {
        System.out.println("BBBB!");
    }
}
```

The output is

AAAA!
BBBB!

And I wonder why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although XProcedure has two methods with the same name - doX, the two signatures are different. The first method gets an instance of class A as a parameter, and the second one gets an instance of class B.

When you call `XProcedure.doX(this)`, the correct method is called according to the class of the passed parameter.

"AAAA!" is printed because of the `super.doY()` call.
"BBBB!" is printed because of the `XProcedure.doX(this);` call.

`this` differs in A's constructor from `this` in B's constructor for the reasons in Che's answer. Although A's contructor is called from within a B's constructor, in A's scope, the instance is of class A.

Comment: The key point is that the overloaded doX method to call is chosen at compile time, based on the *declared* type of the variable. Not at runtime based on the concrete type of the variable. In the method A.doY, the *declared* type of "this" is A, so the first doX method is called. In the method B.doY, the *declared* type of "this" is B, so the second doX method is called. At runtime, the concrete type of this is B in both methods, but the choice of the method to call has been made at compile-time so its concrete type doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1):

You called `super.doY` which is a method on B's superclass A.

All animals can talk.

A cat is an animal.

A cat talks and drinks milk.